# Indicate language for doxygen \include

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to include a `.ini` file in the doxygen documentation of a C++ class, using `\include`. This works fine, but for some reason, doxygen treats the contents of the file as C code, which leads to strange formatting. I know `\include` surrounds the included file with a `\code` block, and that you can pass specific language information to the code block by using e.g. `\code{.unparsed}`. Is there a way to do the same with `\include`? `\include{.unparsed}` does not work...

Comment: Can you use \verbinclude?

Comment: That would work for my purpose. But if there is a way to pass on parameters to the `\code` block, I would still be interested to know how.

Comment: \include takes the file name and determines the language based on the extension (and settings in EXTENSION_MAPPING). The fallback for unknown extensions is C. In case of \code the language of the block is unknown and doesn't have to match language of the file (e.g. a Fortran or C code block in a markdown descriptive text block), therefore the {...} can be specified with \code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the answer to the question is "no": you cannot indicate a language when using `\include`, since doxygen tries to determine the language based on the extension. If it fails to do so, it reverts to C. If you do not want C formatting for unsupported file extensions, you can use `\verbinclude` instead of `\include`.